# Define variables local to tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, variable

I'd like to understand how to **properly** use variables in TikZ.
I've read a large number of Q&A's and, so far, I've encountered `\{g,x,e,}def`,  `\newcommand`, `\pgfmathsetmacro`, and `\let`.

The objective is to parameterise a drawing without repercussions to the rest of the document.

Additionally, the `\foreach` and `[evaluate = <> as <>…]` commands seem also to be creating (local? global?) variables.

Comment: I think that you should propose a minimal example of use. Your current question can bring to an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) .

Comment: Related Question: [What is the preferred way of defining a TikZ constant?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47178/4301). Even thought that question is specfically about constants, same applies to variables.

Comment: Everything defined in the `tikzpicture` should be local to it, unless you explicitly make it `\global` in scope. ie: don't use `\gdef`, `\xdef`. then it won't affect the rest of the code.  As can be seen from `\newcommand{\Foo}{7}
Before:\Foo
\begin{tikzpicture} \def\Foo{11}%
\end{tikzpicture} After:\Foo`. The output before and after the `tikzpicture` is `7` even thought it was defined to be `11` in the `tikzpicture`.  If you want to define `\Foo` before and use it in the `tikzpicture`, then don't redefine it within the `tikzpicture `-- sounds obvious, but I was once bitten by this bug.

Comment: Thank you @PeterGrill, you indeed nailed my question. I didn't think to search for “constant” and indeed it was what I was after. I understand how `\def`, `\newcommand`, `\pgfmathsetmacro`, and `\let` work. Can you point me in the direction for learning about the `{g,x,e}` variants of `\def`? I'll compile a small summary as a self-answer to my question and ask for review / feedback. Moreover, any idea about the local / global behaviour of `\foreach` and `[evaluate` macros?

Comment: Using an `edef` (`\def` with expansion) is still local. The `\gdef` is the equivalent to `\global\def` and `\xdef` is equivalent to `\global\edef`.  More details on those can be found at [What are the differences between \def, \edef, \gdef and \xdef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353138/4301) and [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451/4301).  The `\foreach` loop keep everything local.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the pointers. I'll read up and summarise, citing all the sources.